# How to parse first property in list of JSON objects using Kotlin Serialization?

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin Serialization to parse the JSON data. I just want to parse the first type (eg. grass) to my data class. How do I do that?

```
@Serializable
data class PokemonResponse(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val weight: Double,
    val height: Double
)
```

JSON

```
{
"height": 7,
"id": 1,
"name": "bulbasaur",
"types": [
    {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
            "name": "grass",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
        }
    },
    {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
            "name": "poison",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
        }
    }
],
"weight": 69
}
```

Comment: `I just want to parse the first type (eg. grass) to my data class.` Which grass are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The correct representation of that JSON is the following:

```
@Serializable
data class PokemonResponse(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val types: List<TypeSlot>,
    val weight: Double,
    val height: Double
)
```

```
@Serializable
data class TypeSlot(
    val slot: Integer,
    val type: Type,
)
```

```
@Serializable
data class Type(
    val name: String,
    val url: String,
)
```

To parse the first type you see you would access it like this:
`pokemonResponse.types[0].type.name` given that pokemonResponse is of type PokemonResponse. Gotta catch'em all!